# browser_action icon size changing from 19x to 16x?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I noticed in Canary (currently v53.0.2763.0), with the flag "Material Design in the browser's top chrome" set to "Default" or "Material", Chrome seems to be expecting a 16x size browser_action icon. If not supplied, the 19x icon is scaled and consequently looks fuzzy.

Does anyone know if this is a planned change?

Comment: Yes, https://crbug.com/546206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is live for some users.

Chrome OS started displaying at 16px in version 50. Version 51 on Ubuntu does it too. Both of those use Material Design. Version 51 on Windows 7, which doesn't use MD, still shows a 19px icon.

For now you should include a 16px icon as well as 19px in your "default_icon" section.

Comment: Further to this, the 32px icon (if supplied) will be used at certain screen resolutions.